# Converting text file to dictionary with empty line as the only separator

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, text-files

Hi I'm trying to convert a text file into a dictionary but my separator is an empty line. So an example of part of my `dummy.txt`'s data looks something like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (consectetur adipiscing elit)
2020-01-05 20:01:02
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

Lorem ipsum dolor
2019-01-30 12:21:50 
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem
```

So basically it starts with a name (which sometimes includes brackets), followed by the date and time (as per the format above), followed by any additional information (which could be of any length aka number of rows but contains symbols such as "/" and ","). Lastly, it'll be an empty line to denote the end of the first set of data.

So what I need it to look like, in dictionary form, is this:

```
{'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (consectetur adipiscing elit)':'2020-01-05 20:01:02 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet','Lorem ipsum dolor':'2019-01-30 12:21:50 Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem'}
```

I've tried using a code like this because I can't think of anything else that represents the empty line separator other than "\n", but I know its wrong because `\n` would affect the other data within the same set as well:

```
d = {}
with open("dummy.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split('\n')
        d[key] = val

print (d)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there, you need to split the whole file by double newlines then the key is the first line in that group and the val is all the other lines.

```
d = {}
with open("dummy.txt") as f:
    for group in f.read().split('\n\n'):
      key, *val = group.split('\n')
      d[key] = ' '.join(val)
print (d)
```

Result:

```
{'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (consectetur adipiscing elit)': '2020-01-05 20:01:02 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
 'Lorem ipsum dolor': '2019-01-30 12:21:50  Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the data (file stream) by `\n\n`, and then each item needs to be split by `\n`. According to the structure of your data, the first line in an item is the key and the rest of the lines are concatenated with a whitespace

Some pointers

- Be explicit

  1. Set the mode for `with open` , even if the default is `r`
  2. Use `dict()` instead of `{}` to avoid confusion with a `set`
- Avoid writing a bunch of code in the `with open` block. Fetch the data and close file stream
- `[start=0:stop=end:step=1]` is a great way of getting "the rest of the items in a list"
- Use `json.dumps` to print a pretty message with your data (`indent`,
  `sort_keys`)

```py
import json

d = dict()
with open("dummy.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()

items = data.split("\n\n")

for item in items:
    item_lines = item.split("\n")
    d[item_lines[0]] = " ".join(item_lines[1:])

print(json.dumps(d, indent=2, sort_keys=True))
```

Output

```
{
  "Lorem ipsum dolor": "2019-01-30 12:21:50  Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem",
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (consectetur adipiscing elit)": "2020-01-05 20:01:02 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
}
```